# Creating duplicate entries at Parse Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, parse-server

Trying to create objects within loop.

```
myarray=[1,1,1,1,1];

for (var k = 0; k < myarray.length; k++){
      var id = myarray[k];
      aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id);
}
```

in my aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id) function, I'm trying to check that if i have a parse object with same id. (looking with parsequery) if i have then do not create, just update. But if there isn't object create it and save.

```
function aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id){
   var query= new Parse.Query(MyParseObject);
  query.equalTo("myId",id);

  query.first().then(
        function(result){
               if(result === undefined){
                     // there isn't entry for this id
                     //create parseObject and fill it
                     ...
                      newObject.set("id",id);
                      newObject.save();
               }else{
                       // entry found for this id
                       //do update on result and save
                       ...
                       result.save();
                }
         }
   );

}
```

for my test array (all elements are same id ) it should just create one entry. but i have myarray.length count objects :(

How can i solve this ?

Comment: one thing to note is that you have a typo.  `query.equalTo('myId...)` but you're setting: `newObject.set("id",id);`  So you're setting `id` but looking for `myId`.  As it happens you have a more fundamental problem around promises which I'll explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Promises!

The really short answer is that you're checking five times in a row to see if anything exists before the first object is ever saved.

Ok, now for the long answer.

Your loop calls `aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave`.  The function does its stuff, but the loop doesn't wait for it to do its stuff.  The queries and saving of the object are asynchronous, so the function "returns" right away, even though the queries it invokes keep running.

Hopefully, I can make it clear what is going on:

1. I'll make a minor adjustment to your code that will "prove" what is going on
2. I'll show you how to do it with promise goodness ;).
3. And finally, if you want to have a unique id, make sure to add a unique index on your backing store (mongo?).

The first code listing here is a unit test with more or less your code, plus a test at the end to hopefully show what is going on....

```
// testing boilerplate 2 lines...
describe('my test', () => {
  it('count', (done) => {
    // ok, this is all "our code"        
    const MyParseObject = 'TestClass';

    // a function to count number of records with a given id.
    // Importantly, this function returns a promise.
    const count =  function count(id) {
      return new Parse.Query(MyParseObject)
        .equalTo('myId', id)
        .count(); // <-- count returns a promise
    }

     // your function with all the ...'s filled in.
    function aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id){
      var query = new Parse.Query(MyParseObject);
      query.equalTo("myId",id);
      query.first().then(
        function(result){
          if(result === undefined){
            // there isn't entry for this id
            //create parseObject and fill it
            const newObject = new Parse.Object(MyParseObject);
            newObject.set('myId',id);
            // you don't wait for this promise to resolve!
            newObject.save();
          } else {
            // entry found for this id
            // do update on result and save
            result.increment('count');
            // this never gets called, and is never waited on...
            result.save();
          }
        });
    }

    const myarray = [1,1,1,1,1];

    for (var k = 0; k < myarray.length; k++){
      var id = myarray[k];
      aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id);
    }

    // so what I'm doing here is waiting for 
    // 1 second, then counting the number
    // of records with the same 'myId'.
    // and then testing that each id in the array 
    // got a new object.
    setTimeout(() => {
      count(id)
        // count will be 5 and that's one per element in myarray
        .then(count => expect(count).toBe(myarray.length))
        .then(done)
        .catch(done.fail)
    }, 1000); // 1,000 miliseconds is one second
  });
});
```

Below is how I "fixed" the code to only create one object and also increment a counter on each iteration.

```
describe('my test', () => {
  const MyParseObject = 'TestClass';

  it('count', (done) => {
    // This will call an array of functions that return promises in sequence.
    const sequence = function sequence(tasks) {
      return tasks.reduce((promise, task) => promise.then(() => task.call()), Promise.resolve());
    }

    function aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id){
      var query = new Parse.Query(MyParseObject);
      query.equalTo("myId",id);

      // Very important to return this promise!
      return query.first().then(
        function(result){
          if(result === undefined){
            // there isn't an entry for this id
            //create parseObject and fill it
            const newObject = new Parse.Object(MyParseObject);
            newObject.set('myId', id);
            newObject.set('count', 1);
            // very important to return this promise!
            return newObject.save();
          } else {
            // entry found for this id
            //do update on result and save
            result.increment('count');
            // very important to return this promise!
            return result.save();
          }
        });
    }

    const myarray = [1,1,1,1,1];
    const promises = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < myarray.length; k++){
      var id = myarray[k];
      // don't call the function, make an array of functions that call the functions.
      promises.push(() => aFunctionCreatesParseObjectAndSave(id));
    }

    // We have an array promises that haven't even started to run.
    // the function sequence() will now execute each promise
    // in the array, then wait till its done and start the next
    // promise.
    sequence(promises)
      .then(() => new Parse.Query(MyParseObject).find())
      .then(results => {
        // this test verifies that there is only one object now.
        expect(results.length).toBe(1);
        const theObj = results[0];
        // the count member of the object should be 5, one for each 
        // id element of 1 in 'myarray'
        expect(theObj.get('count')).toBe(myarray.length);
        done();
      })
      .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```

The test that I did here is in the context of running unit tests on a nodejs server.  And I wrote a `sequence` function.  "In real life", especially if this code is running in a browser, you'd want to use a library like bluebird and then use [mapSeries](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html).